# Add a list of integers into a csv file (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist, statistics, export-to-csv

All I want is to add a list of numbers from an algorithm (which is really long so I won't show it here but gave an output of [2039, 25553, 189030, 1449869, 134295, 352258, 1588788, 718293, 353578, 1495712, 539563, 1691741, 1032543, 362844, 1143463, 4671463])

```
List<Integer> List1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

to a csv file and produce a line graph from it.
I've done some searching for answers but I couldn't find anything specific for this.
**Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Try
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        List<Integer> List1 = new ArrayList<>();

        //For the example, i populate the list
        List1.add(123);
        List1.add(456);
        List1.add(789);

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("outNumbers.csv"));

        List1.stream().forEach(i->outFile.print(i + ", "));

        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better will be using try with resources. Or close steam at finally block.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer,it was much appreciated.  Also, how could I put this list in a formatted table with a y and x axis detailing their values? Such that the code ```List1.add(123);
        List1.add(456);
        List1.add(789);``` Could be formatted in a table so 123 could be under column named "one" on row named "one" etc